# Log tampering - edit notifications

Tags: tampering

Hello Guys I am looking for a solution that can record the log tamper event and notify(email/sms) what the change made in the log file and it should be limit to specific paragraph instead of listing complete file and highlighting the changes.

Comment: windows? linux? link to what you mean by log "tamper event"?